# starting a app with a defined windows size each time

Tags: macos, swiftui, window, size

I have an app with a vertical resizable window. The height (Scrollview) will be resizes automatically by the scrollview content. But the user can resize the window height by himself, if needed.
I want to make sure, the app window start every time with a definite "start size". But the app seems to remember the manually resizing of the window.

I tried to define a startup size under appDelegate:

```
let initialWindowSize = NSSize(width: 800, height: 600)
    NSApp.mainWindow?.setContentSize(initialWindowSize)
```

or set a default windows size to the WindowGroup:

```
WindowGroup {
...
}
.defaultSize(width: 800, height: 600)
```

and the ContentView have a defined size too:

```
ContentView(...).frame(minWidth: 800, minHeight: 600)
```

But the app seems to remember the previous windows before quitting the app and start the app with these old sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Founded ...

AppDelegate -->

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        if let Panel = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
            let contentRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600)
            Panel.setContentSize(contentRect.size)
            Panel.isRestorable = false
        }
        
    }
```

I think, the key is "NSApplication.shared.windows.first" to address the right window and isRestorable = false.